# how performance of a volume can be reduced by up to 200 percent

Tags: windows, performance, windows-server-2012-r2

i'm not sure if this is the right place to ask

when executing backup of the windows server with Windows backup utility, at the specify destination type screen, there is a note under backup to volume option, this one :

> Choose this option if you cannot dedicate an entire disk for backups.
>   Note that the performance of the volume may be reduced by up to 200
>   percent while it is used to store backups. we recommend that you do
>   not store other server data on the same volume.

i took a screenshot you can find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7k6l.png)

My question is how the performance can be reduced by more than 100 percent ?
if the I/O performance measurement is 60MB/s for example, will it be -60MB/s if reduced by 200 percent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just play of words that say you need longer time to complete particular task, with inappropriate terms.

Say a typical disk will churn out 500 I/O per seconds(IOPS)
To store bunch of data that need 2000 I/O to perform, the time required will be

> 2000 IO / 500 IOPS = 4 seconds (typical task)

Now, say the backup will required 8000 IO, so to complete the backup

> 8000 IO/ 500 IOPS = 16 seconds (backup task)

When both disk IO task are carry out, now typical task need to compete with the backup task I/O resources, it end up typical task took 8 seconds to return the results.

> (8 /4 )seconds = 2 times longer than original task

Apparently `smart aleck` that proofreading the technical manual attempt to outsmart everyone by replacing 2 times with 200% . While in fact, 2 times is NOT always equal to 200%.